# Printing out a matrix into a file from Fortran

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, fortran, output

I have a large, usually square, matrix which I calculate in Fortran. After this, I need to print out this array into a .txt or .dat file so that it can be read by Python. Initially I had problems since the format of the array kept getting changed ( meaning the rows and columns got messed up), but I managed to find a way to reconstruct the array in Python via the following method:

say I have a 1000 x 1000 matrix, and then to print it out I do

```
open(6,file='/home/alpha_x.dat')
do i =1,1000
    write(6,'(1000F14.7)')(alpha_x(i,j), j=1,1000)
end do 
open(5,file='/home/alpha_y.dat')
do i =1,1000
    write(5,'(1000F14.7)')(alpha_y(i,j), j=1,1000)
end do
```

Afterwards to read this in Python, I simply use

```
np.loadtxt('alpha_x.dat')
alpha_x = np.transpose(alpha_x)#This is required since the row-column order is interchanged in Fortran and Python
```

This worked fine until I realised that, for example, if I had a matrix with dimensions 2000 x 2000 and I do all this in Fortran and read it in Python, the array turns out to have dimensions 4000 x 1000. I can't help but think that this means there must be something wrong in the way I save the matrix in Fortran...Seems as if the matrix is somehow converted into n columns x 1000 rows for whatever multiple. How would I fix this so that I can reconstruct the array with original dimensions in Python?

Comment: Do you change the format, which is specific to the number of columns, on output to match the new size?

Comment: Oh you mean 1000F14.7 this bit? so if its a 2000 x 2000 matrix you mean it should be 2000F14.7?

Comment: Yes.  There will be other questions here about how to tailor a format to the matrix size, so you won't need to manually change all the time.

Comment: ahhhhh works like a charm!...you're right...I've really tried to search for posts where there is a good way for dealing with matrix output but failed to find a generalised way as of yet...will keep checking I suppose

Comment: Yes, there are many duplicates. Cannot search now, maybe later if nobody else does that in the mean time.